# Can routed ships retreat to port in the same sea area?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Playing the Game of Thrones board game and using the Clash of Kings Port rules expansion, I was Stark and my ships in the Narrow Sea were attacked by Baratheon and lost. Baratheon didn't have any swords, so my two ships were still alive, but routed. However, there were no rules describing whether routed ships could enter the port of the same sea, in which I had just lost the battle, or whether I was required to retreat to another sea area.

It's difficult because the port in the Narrow Sea is controlled by the land area of White Harbor, which I owned, so there's an argument that the routed ships could limp into port. But I could also see Baratheon's view that he won the sea battle and it was a little unfair that I could limp into port in the sea area he has just taken, only for me to recover and attack in the next few rounds, especially after he just defeated me. In fact this is exactly what happened next turn, because there was a mustering and I reclaimed the sea. Baratheon wanted me to retreat into the Shivering Sea, as the ships would have fled the battle after losing.

As the decision would affect the whole game and the deciding player didn't want to decide, we flicked a coin.

Any suggestions? Can routed ships limp into a port of the same sea area, or do they have to retreat to another sea area?

Answer (score 16):

The port is never considered "part" of the sea area; control of a port depends on whoever controls the land area, and the sea area is merely adjacent.  The ability to use a port despite the adjacent sea area being occupied is probably the most important aspect of ports.

From [the FAQ](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/a_game_of_thrones_the_board_game/media/agotfaq.pdf):

> *Q: Can a fleet that is defeated in a sea area retreat to a friendly Port touching that sea area?*
>
> A: Yes.

Comment: Thanks this really clarifies things. I never saw this FAQ page before - really useful thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With the proviso that I'm not an expert at this game: I don't see any problem with routed ships retreating into a port of the same sea.

From the base rules, routed troops must retreat into a legal adjacent area.  The Clash of Kings port rules describe Ports as new "special areas between the Land and Sea area".  From the way your question is stated it seems like your friend has a problem with you retreating into a port "in the sea area he has just taken" - but the port is not technically *in* that area, rather between that area and the land.

So my initial interpretation would be that the retreat into port is perfectly fair.  Where else would ships attacked just outside their home port retreat to?